# How to divide array in parts with a token?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
foreach ($infos->find('.products-list-item .products-list-item__sizes') as $sizes_info) 
{
    while($size = $sizes_info->children($k++))
    {
        $sizes_arr[] = $size->plaintext;
    }
    $sizes_arr[] = '_';
    $k=0;
}
```

it looks like:

```
array(412) { [0]=> string(2) "XXL" [1]=> string(1) "S" [2]=> string(1) "M" [3]=> string(1) "L" [4]=> string(1) "_" [5]=> string(2) "43" [6]=> string(2) "44".....and so on
```

I need to divide this array in arrays with by a sign "_"... in other words I need to get this:

```
 array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "XXL" [1]=> string(1) "S" [2]=> string(1) "M" [3]=> string(1) "L"}
 array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "43" [1]=> string(1) "44"}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you're forming your array in such way if you need it in another way? Simply do:

```
foreach ($infos->find('.products-list-item .products-list-item__sizes') as $sizes_info) {
    $sizes_tmp = []; //or $sizes_tmp = array(); for PHP<=5.3
    while ($size = $sizes_info->children($k++)) {
        $sizes_tmp[] = $size->plaintext;
    }
    $sizes_arr[] = $sizes_tmp;
    $k=0;//not sure what is it. leaving it as it is
}
```